# What is the best way to parse huge xml files in Java without getting GC errors

Tags: java, xml, crash, garbage-collection

I have run across an issue where using DocumentBuilderFactory we occasionally experience complete failure on processes where the XML files are extremely large (over 100 Meg).  It doesn't just throw an error, it crashes hard without the ability to even write an error to the log.  There has been some debate on what to set for the max and min heap size, our settings are currently:

```
Xmx=Xmx6g
Xms=Xms2g
```

We are running up to 12 processes concurrently on a 30G ram box.  I think the `Xms` value should be dropped (it helped, I wasn't listened to :) ) and the `Xmx` raised to 12g.  I'd appreciate any insight into this issue; do we dump the factory builder we are using, or do we tweak the memory settings and buy a bigger box?

Comment: Use a streaming parser, like SAX, instead of trying to load it all into memory at once.

Comment: *Opinion:* I would suggest [StAX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/stax/index.html) over [SAX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/sax/index.html). Both are built into Java, and can handle infinitely large XML, unlike the [DOM](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/dom/index.html) you're trying to use. There are also third-party libraries that may help.

Comment: @shmosel - thanks!  SAX Parser will likely be the way, though I would have preferred to handle this in a dev ops manner.

Comment: @Andreas - much obliged, will check out out.

Comment: maybe your process is getting killed by the kernel's OOM killer. In that case you need to add swap or more ram if you want a "devops solution". The former will likely kill your performance once it gets used. using a streaming parser takes more development effort but it'll be more scalable

Comment: It all depends what you actually want to do with the the data once it has been parsed. Perhaps it's a task suitable for XSLT 3.0 streaming, or for XQuery with document projection (see my XML Prague 2017 paper for a comparison of these techniques.)

Comment: I've downvoted the question because there's not enough information to answer it. We can't know what the best way of meeting your requirements is without knowing a lot more about the requirements.

Comment: @MichaelKay I believe that was a bit harsh, perhaps instead of down-voting you could have clarified what was missing

Comment: I thought I did say what was missing: we need to know what the user wants to do with the data after parsing it.